# Circular Header Import, Enum Unrecognized

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch

I've got two Cocoa Touch classes (objective-c). And both `#import` each other's header.

Class A's header defines an enum, which Class B's header is trying to use. Class B fails to compile due to not recognizing the type.

I think this is a circular dependency issue, but I think `@class` won't be too much help since the issue is with an enum.

What do you suggest?

Comment: What does the Class A header use from the Class B header?

Comment: Right now, just the class name. But (unless my design proves unfeasible) it'll eventually use its properties and methods.

The reverse however isn't true, Class B could go without using anything but the enum type from Class A. Perhaps I could move the enums into a "Common.h" header.

Comment: Yeah, a "Common.h" for the enum sound like a good plan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the enum in it's own header and forward declare the classes with @class where needed in each others headers so A don't need to import B and B don't need to import A but booth import the enum header.

Answer (score 0):

in header files use `@class ClassName;`
and in .m file use import.

Comment: Still won't compile; the type still remains unrecognized in class B.